# How to make trigger script work in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

My intention is to generate a random number on a specific cell everytime I select anything on my sheet. So what should I do in order to make this code below work?

```
/**
 * The event handler triggered when the selection changes in the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onSelectionChange event.
 */
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  // Set background to red if a single empty cell is selected.
  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getNumRows() === 1 
      && range.getNumColumns() === 1 
      && range.getCell(1, 1).getValue() === "") {
      range.set(RAND());
  }
}
```

when I execute the code above I just got error like this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 7, file "triggers")`

this is my first time utilizing script tool in sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- `onSelectionChange` is the function for the simple trigger. And `e` of `onSelectionChange(e)` is the event trigger. When the event is fired, `e` has the value. So from your error message of `Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`, I thought that you might be directly run the function `onSelectionChange` at the script editor. In this case, the event object is not given. By this, such error occurs.
- In your script, there is a modification point. I think that `range.set(RAND());` might be `range.setValue(RAND());`.
- I think that `range.getCell(1, 1).getValue() === ""` can be modified to `range.isBlank()`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
/**
 * The event handler triggered when the selection changes in the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onSelectionChange event.
 */
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  // Set background to red if a single empty cell is selected.
  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getNumRows() === 1 
      && range.getNumColumns() === 1 
      && range.isBlank()) {  // Modified
      range.setValue(RAND());  // Modified
  }
}
```

- In order to run this function, please copy and paste above script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and save the script. And, please select a cell on the Spreadsheet. By this, `onSelectionChange` is run by the simple trigger.
- In this modification, it supposes that the function `RAND()` works.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

  - [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

### Added:

When you want to put the value of `RAND()` to the cell "A1" when the cell is selected, how about the following script?

#### Sample script:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  e.range.getSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(RAND());
}
```

#### Sample situation:

As a sample situation, when this script is used, the following result can be seen.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  e.range.getSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(Math.random());
}
```

[image]

Comment: supposely Row1Column1 should be A1 right? I saved the script and going back to my sheets, but when I tried to select anything randomly, A1 still the same, no changes. I'm not sure if the script is running or not.

Comment: @Ahiung Lim Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I added one more script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? That script puts the value of `RAND()` to the cell "A1" when the cell is selected.

Comment: hmm weird, not working. do I have to somehow connect the script to the  related sheet like the addon thing? it seems that the script is not running at all.

Comment: your english is perfectly fine, I prefer basic english rather than scholar level english.

Comment: @Ahiung Lim Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in my environment, I can confirm that the script works. So I proposed this as an answer. So I deeply apologize for this situation. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Ahiung Lim In order to run the function of `onSelectionChange`, for example, how about putting `console.log(e)` in the function of `onSelectionChange`, and selecting a cell on Spreadsheet, and then, checking the log at Apps Script Dashboard? If the function is run, you can see it as the log. But I found [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157856455). In this case, it seems that this trigger didn't work at Jun 2, 2020. In my environment, I could confirm that this trigger worked at 18 May 2020. So I'm worry about whether releasing this trigger is different for the area.

Comment: @Ahiung Lim I added a sample situation in my answer. Could you please confirm it? When above sample script is used, when the cell is clicked, you can see that the value of the cell "A1" is changed. If in your environment, even when you use above script, the value of cell "A1" is not changed, how about reporting this issue to the issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: hey, I tried the code from your sample situation and it works!

Comment: @Ahiung Lim Welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, thank you for your response.

Comment: sorry, forgot the tick the solution button because I was writing another question lol, btw, Tanaike, you have been very helpful. I thank for that.